# Porting Serial.write(Byte, int, int) from C# to Python using Pyserial

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, pyserial

I have code written in C# that I want to port to Python.

I want to port `Serial.write(Byte, int, int)` from C# to Python and I am using Pyserial. I tried `Serial.Write` in Pyserial but wasn't able to get the work done.

Can anyone guide me through how to create a similar function in Python?

Comment: It's a shame to be the StackOverflow stereotype here, but you should really start out with the examples on the man-page: https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html. And when that doesn't work, give us a relevant - and short - piece of code that you're having trouble with. And the error it produces and what your expected result is.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html), you need to write `bytes`, not numbers.

So you need to convert your numbers, which are one `byte` and two `int`, to bytes.

You can do that with the `struct` module. See the [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) method.